# openframeworks library problem with iphone apps only not with mac apps

Tags: iphone, opencv, openframeworks

I have downloaded latest openframeworks library from github.

I am able to run all mac examples. But I dont know whats wrong with iphone samples. None of the iphone examples are running. Showing lots of error everytime.

Is it problem with existing code or I have to do some settings ?

> Update: These are list of few errors:

[image]

Comment: Haven't used openframeworks but other C++ stuff. Can you specify what went wrong in more detail, i.e. compiler or runtime errors, what kind of errors,.. ?

Comment: Can you please post the first few errors from build output to get an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Please refer attached screenshot in this thread. So, these are list of some errors out of 97 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there are a couple of frameworks missing like for example CoreMedia. Add them step by step via "Add Files to "MyProject":

[image]

To get an idea of what frameworks are missing, just look into the docs of the affected classes e.g. CMSampleBuffer belongs to CoreMedia.framework

Comment: There n numbers of errors in different different samples. So should I have to file a bug on openframeworks ? Because all MAC sourcecodes are working fine. Problem is in with every iphone samples.

Comment: Well if they supply an XCode project supposed to be ready to run, then yes. But you can try to fix it o your own. It is pretty simple (if there are no more issues) and you will be ready to go within 1h.

Answer (score 0):

Do they run in the simulator?

If they run in the simulator but not in your iPhone, that's probably because you don't have a developer profile installed (you can enroll here for $99/year http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/ )

openFrameworks samples used to come signed with the developer profile of somebody at openFramework's team, which is not valid in your computer

Comment: Hey Marc, Its not related to iphone/Simulator. That Library samples avaiable for different devices like iphone/Mac etc. So all MAC applications are running fine. But iphone samples are completely buggy